# Python site-packages import

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I have a site-packages folder in an environment. This is containing the exemplary site-package 'test'. 
Now in this "\lib\site-package\test" there are two files. **init**.py and testwrapper.py.

**init**.py:

```
import testwrapper
Testclass = testwrapper.Testclass()
```

When I run this **init**.py in an IDE it perfectly initiates this "Testclass" and I can use it with as an example `Testclass.exampleFunction()`.

When I now run the python console and type `import test`, it finds the site-package and imports it. But I can not use `Testclass.exampleFunction()` as I can in the IDE, because `Testclass` is unknown. I can use it if I type in the code from the **init**.py manually, thus in the console:

```
import test

import testwrapper
Testclass = testwrapper.Testclass()
Testclass.exampleFunction()
```

This works just fine in the console. But as far as I understood, if I import the site-package by using `import test` the **init**.py shall automatically be loaded and started? 
Thanks for the help in understanding guys.